# How to make a range tree implementation thread safe

Tags: java, algorithm, concurrency, binary-tree, graph-theory

I've implemented a range tree which supports updates in the form of incrementing or decrementing the count of a specific value. It can also query the number of values lower or equal to the value provided.

The range tree has been tested to work in a single threaded environment, however I would like to know how to modify the implementation such that it can be updated and queried concurrently.

I know a simple solution would be to synchronise methods that access this tree, but I would like to know if there are ways to make RangeTree thread safe by itself with minimal affect on performance.

```
public class RangeTree {

    public static final int ROOT_NODE = 0;

    private int[] count;
    private int[] min;
    private int[] max;

    private int levels;
    private int lastLevelSize;

    public RangeTree(int maxValue) {

        levels = 1;
        lastLevelSize = 1;
        while (lastLevelSize <= maxValue) {
            levels++;
            lastLevelSize = lastLevelSize << 1;
        }

        int alloc = lastLevelSize * 2;
        count = new int[alloc];
        min = new int[alloc];
        max = new int[alloc];

        int step = lastLevelSize;
        int pointer = ROOT_NODE;
        for (int i = 0; i < levels; i++) {
            int current = 0;
            while (current < lastLevelSize) {
                min[pointer] = current;
                max[pointer] = current + step - 1;
                current += step;
                pointer++;
            }
            step = step >> 1;
        }
    }

    public void register(int value) {
        int index = lastLevelSize - 1 + value;
        count[index]++;

        walkAndRefresh(index);
    }

    public void unregister(int value) {
        int index = lastLevelSize - 1 + value;
        count[index]--;

        walkAndRefresh(index);
    }

    private void walkAndRefresh(int node) {
        int currentNode = node;
        while (currentNode != ROOT_NODE) {
            currentNode = (currentNode - 1) >> 1;
            count[currentNode] = count[currentNode * 2 + 1] + count[currentNode * 2 + 2];
        }
    }

    public int countLesserOrEq(int value) {
        return countLesserOrEq0(value, ROOT_NODE);
    }

    private int countLesserOrEq0(int value, int node) {
        if (max[node] <= value) {
            return count[node];
        } else if (min[node] > value) {
            return 0;
        }
        return countLesserOrEq0(value, node * 2 + 1) + countLesserOrEq0(value, node * 2 + 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly?  Probably not.  There's not going to be any nice way to do this.  If you do manage to do it, it'd be worth a nice research paper.

Comment: @LouisWasserman it is hard indeed. However, I think it would be easier if it is implemented as an actual tree ( with nodes) so locking can be done on nodes being mutated.

Answer (score 1):

Louis Wasserman is right, this is a difficult question. But it may have simple solution.

Depending on your updates/reads ratio and the contention for the data, it *may be* useful to use [ReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) instead of synchronized.

Another solution which *may be* efficient in some cases (depends on your workload) is to copy whole `RangeTree` object before update and then switch the reference to 'actual' `RangeTree`. Like it is done in [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html). But this also violates atomic consistency agreement and leads us to eventual consistency.